# Default user relationships with the site admin

Tags: 7, users

I am using the User Relationships module for my Drupal7 site. I have created a one way relationship with reciprocal by the name "Follower". So if User A can be followed by User B. Also, User A can follow User B. Now i set out in the process of creating a default relationship. I did that but it works only one way. I want that by default all user follow and are followed by the ADMIN. the default relationship that i created through the CMS works fine but it works only one way. I see that Admin is following the users but not vice-versa. Also, this happens only for new users of the site. I do not see old users having that default relationships. How can i achieve that? Any suggestions.

Comment: i tried with Rules but to no effect...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to achieve this with `rules` + `user relationship rules` modules.

**Export:**

```
{ "rules_follow" : {
    "LABEL" : "follow",
    "PLUGIN" : "reaction rule",
    "REQUIRES" : [ "user_relationships_rules", "rules" ],
    "ON" : [ "user_insert" ],
    "DO" : [
      { "user_relationships_rules_action_create_relationship" : {
          "relationship_type" : "1",
          "requester" : [ "account" ],
          "requestee" : "1",
          "approve" : 1
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

**Rule Details:**
Event: *After saving a new user account*

Conditions: *None*

Action: *Request, create or approve relationships between users*

**Rule Settings:**
Relationship Type: *[your defined relationship] (follower)*

Requestor: (Data Selection Method) Data selector "account"

Requestee: (Direct input mode) "1" (or the user ID of your admin account)

Approve Relationship: TRUE